# Prove or disprove: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Prove or disprove: The following series is convergent
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}= \frac{\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}\right)}{k\sqrt{k} \cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}\right)}= \frac{k+1-k}{k\sqrt{k} \cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k} \cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(k\sqrt{k}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1}\right)+k\sqrt{k}\cdot\sqrt{k}}= \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}\cdot \left(\sqrt{k+1}\right)+k^{2}}< \frac{1}{k^{2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$$

This is a convergent series and thus the original series is convergent as well.

---

- Did I do everything correcty (I'm especially not sure about the last step where I used "<")?
- Is there another way of proofing convergence here without that much work? I have tried ratio test too but it got so complicated and I couldn't solve it

Comment: looks fine to me (+1)

Comment: for big enough $k$ you can just taylorexpand $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{1/k}+\mathcal{O}(1/k)$ to reach the same conclusion

Comment: Wow you see so fast, thank you! :D You know if there is an easier / faster way?

Comment: have a look at my second comment

Comment: $<\sum \frac{1}{2k^2}=\frac{{\pi}^2}{3}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{k\sqrt{k}}< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\zeta (\frac{3}{2})$$

Comment: How would you continue after? I think there will be problems getting $k^{2}$ in the denominator?

Comment: Doesn't matter since $\sum_k \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges when $p>1$.

Comment: Ohhh that's very important info for me, didn't know that, thanks so much!

Comment: @tenepolis according to Reimann criteria the series is converge

Comment: We didn't have Reimann in our readings, do you think we are allowed to use it in the exam then? Because if I know how to use it, why should I be forbidden to do it? You know or you think I shouldn't better do it? It saves a lot time for sure..

Comment: @tenepolis It is probably beyond the scope of your course. However, I'm sure you have learned the [P-series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) converges for $p> 1$